# MacBook Pro 2018 ventilation slots blocked

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, battery

I bought my MacBook Pro in October 2018. Now, on both the left and the right side of the machine's backside (the bottom) both the ventilation slots show some kind of foil coming out. The foil is coming out of the vents exactly symmetrically and it's slowly getting worse. Now about 4cm of foil are visible on each side.

I went to a premium reseller and they said they rarely see this and they said it might be the battery coming out which is unsettling.

I do perform calculations for my university course so R or Python might run for a while but I don't think this would cause harm to the laptop to this extent.

Has anybody else had this issue?

[image: one side ventilation slot]

Comment: If you bought this laptop new from Apple (or authorized reseller) then it's still under warranty.  You should have it replaced.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here as the question is worded to only give a "yes/no" answer.  Regardless, this is a *physical* issue; even if it's nothing more than loose foil blocking the vents, you have to take it in for service.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **Customer Support** questions are outside of the scope of what can be asked here as defined in the [Help Center](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I didn't think this was a customer support issue solely, because it could have been caused by something that I did. Sorry for asking this in the wrong way, please do close the question if you feel it is outside the scope.

Answer (score 1):

Apple had to replace the entire bottom plate (within warranty) of the MacBook. The foil is not related to the battery but rather a sort of inner lining that runs along the sides. The people at genius bar couldn't state any apparent reason for this happening.